# Injecting a DbContext with an async constructor dependency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, async-await, simple-injector

The goal is to construct a `DbContext` with a connection that uses an access token. The access token is acquired with ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library).

The problem is that acquiring an access token is an async operation. Luckily, [ADAL uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` for its async calls](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/504), so it should be safe to do sync-over-async without risking deadlocks.

Full code is provided below. The focus for this question is on the sync-over-async code and method of registering the `DbContext`, but remarks for the other code are welcome too.

**Container configuration**

```
private Container CreateContainer(AppSettings.Root appSettings)
{
    var container = new Container();
    /*
     * AsyncScopedLifestyle is recommended for Web API applications.
     * https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#asyncscoped-vs-webrequest
     */
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    container.Register<ITokenProvider>(
        () => new TokenProvider(appSettings.Azure.TenantId, appSettings.Azure.ClientId, appSettings.Azure.ClientCertificateSDN),
        Lifestyle.Singleton
        );

    container.Register<IConnectionFactory, ConnectionFactory>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    container.Register(
        () => new FooDbContext(container.GetInstance<IConnectionFactory>().CreateConnection(appSettings.Foo.Database.ConnectionString)),
        Lifestyle.Scoped
        );

    /*
     * Calling Verify is not required, but is highly encouraged.
     * https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#verifying-the-container-s-configuration
     */
    container.Verify();

    return container;
}
```

**Token provider**

```
public interface ITokenProvider
{
    Task<string> GetDatabaseAccessToken();
}

public sealed class TokenProvider
    : ITokenProvider
{
    /*
     * Asynchronous calls have ConfigureAwait(false) to allow sync-over-async without risking a deadlock, e.g. when a token is required during construction.
     * ADAL supports this as per https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/504.
     */

    private readonly string tenantId;

    private readonly string clientId;

    private readonly X509Certificate2 clientCertificate;

    public TokenProvider(
        string tenantId,
        string clientId,
        string clientCertificateSDN
        )
    {
        this.tenantId = tenantId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tenantId));
        this.clientId = clientId ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));

        using (var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
        {
            certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            this.clientCertificate = certificateStore.Certificates
                .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, clientCertificateSDN ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientCertificateSDN)), false)
                [0];
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string resource)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");
        var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(this.clientId, this.clientCertificate);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientAssertionCertificate).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetDatabaseAccessToken()
    {
        return await this.GetAccessToken("https://database.windows.net/").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

**Connection factory**

```
public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    SqlConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString);
}

public sealed class ConnectionFactory
    : IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly ITokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public ConnectionFactory(ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenProvider));
    }

    public SqlConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        {
            AccessToken = this.tokenProvider.GetDatabaseAccessToken().Result
        };
    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public partial class FooDbContext
    : DbContext
{
    public FooDbContext(SqlConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your `TokenProvider` class has a dependency on a `X509Certificate2`. Is this intended to be lazy loaded? I would probably generate the certificate inside your `CreateContainer` method and add that to the container as a singleton. This way if it fails, it "fails fast" on startup, and potentially other future classes have access to that certificate.

Comment: @BradM Good point, the certificate will eventually be used by other parts of the application, so indeed it makes sense to retrieve it in the container. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind me asking, any reason you want to register the DbContext directly? I know .NET Core seems to want you to do that, but I don't like IoC containers deciding when to leave open or close my DB connections.  Insetead, I'd just do IFooDbContextFactory and have that use a "CreateAsync" method.  This factory can take your IAppSettings or IDbContextSettings or something to get the connection string.  Then you can call the provider async just fine and in your specific code you'd just do:

```
public class FooDbContextFactory : IFooDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IFooDbContextSettings _settings;
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public FooDbContextFactory(IFooDbContextSettings settings, ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public async Task<FooDbContext> CreateAsync()
    {
       var token = await _tokenPRovider.GetToken(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
       return new FooDbContext(...);
    }
}

public class SomeRepository
{
    private reaonly IFooDbContextFactory _factory;
    public SomeRepository(IFooDbContextFactory factory)
    {
       _factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<SomeEntity>> GetSomeList()
    {
       using (var context = await _factory.CreateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
       {
          return await context.Somes().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I don't like IoC containers deciding when to leave open or close my DB connections_ and they don't if you tell them not to. [Four ways to dispose IDisposables in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/four-ways-to-dispose-idisposables-in-asp-net-core/) or with Autofac you can mark a dependency as [ExternallyOwned](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html).

Comment: People can make mistakes with this configuration. With a factory and using statement there is no question when this gets disposed and you don't have to worry about other applications using this code configure it incorrectly

Comment: This is a very good argument...  to kill every idea because people can make mistakes with just anything :-| With a properly configured DI container I have less worries then by maintaining my own solutions. I like the smiley ;-)

Comment: I just like having control over my database connections. I know when I'm done so I kill it as soon as I'm done with it.

Comment: Plus if you are doing calls in parallel you'd need multiple instances of dbcontext since you can't share them. Thus you'd need a factory for that anyway. Plus you can have more control over the configuration on it.